# Can't using spl_autoload_register to load classes in PHP

Tags: php, file, path, autoload, spl-autoload-register

I just encountered an error while programming PHP. The thing is that I used `spl_autoload_register` inside the `init.php` file but could not load the classes inside the classes folder. I make sure that the classes inside the files in the classes folder have the same name as the file name. And if I don't use `spl_autoload_register` and `include_once` on each file, it works (I commented the included_once files manually). Please give me a solution. Here is my directory structure:

[This is my project folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n090e.png)

Here is the code inside the `init.php` file:

```php
<?php
include_once dirname(__DIR__) . "/inc/" . "config.php"; 


// include_once dirname(__DIR__) . "/classes/" . "database.php"; 
// include_once dirname(__DIR__) . "/classes/" . "user.php"; 
// include_once dirname(__DIR__) . "/classes/" . "student.php"; 

// Auto load class
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    include_once dirname(__DIR__) . "/classes/" . strtolower($class) . ".php"; 
});
?>
```

I tried changing the available paths, but it didn't seem to work the way I wanted, I also thought maybe I had the wrong path

Comment: Welcome to SO, what is your problem? What is the debugging trace? Does there any error logs?

Comment: Hi, I tried echo $class of the callback but I don't get anything, I think the autoload function doesn't receive anything from the classes folder. And the system does not report any errors @hassan

Comment: Please be more accurate in what you write. I don't know what: _"I don't get anything"_, means. Do you get an empty page? Are you a 100% sure the `$class` parameter is empty? Did you use something like: `echo "[class=$class]";`, or even: `echo "[class=$class," . (empty($class) ? "yes" : "no") . "]";`?

Comment: Are you using [namespaces](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php)?

Comment: I didn't use namespace sir

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that when using `spl_autoload_register` you need to initialize an object for the program to actually load.

Comment: What does this mean?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).